# MVC C# WebGrid, column sorted in ascending order, first click does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a `WebGrid` with `canSort: true`, when the grid first loads, if a column is already sorted in ascending order, clicking the column header the *first time* does nothing. Then the second click sorts the column in descending order.

When a WebGrid loads and a column is already sorted in ascending order, how can I have the *first click* sort the column in descending order?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you specified the `defaultSort` property? How are you telling the WebGrid that it is already sorted in a particular order?

Comment: I was not using `default sort`. I have now added it, it solves the issue for that column (Thanks!)  but it does not solve the issue with the other columns. The list of items in the grid can be short and a column may be in ascending already before clicking on the header.